# disable/enable drop down list based on time

Tags: php

```
<?php 

    //If statement to control pick selection "disabled/enabled"
if(strtotime("Today") == strtotime("Thursday") || strtotime("Friday") ||   strtotime("Saturday") || strtotime("Sunday") || strtotime("Monday")) {
echo '<h2>Make a selection! Picks are now  available</h2>';

$pick = $_POST['teams'];
    if(isset($_POST['teams'])) {
        echo '<br><p>You have made a selection,  feel free to change your pick until ONE HOUR before game time.<p><br>';
    }
}


?>

<html>
<body>

<h3>Pick</h3>

<div class="loginForm">
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Pick</legend>
    <select id="tm1" name="teams">
    <option value="null"> Please Select Your Pick</option>
    <option value="wr">Washington Redskins</option>
    <option value="nyg">New York Giants</option>
    <option value="pe">Philadelphia Eagles</option>
    <option value="dc">Dallas Cowboys</option>
    <option value="br">Baltimore Ravens</option>
    <option value="ps">Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
    <option value="tt">Tennessee Titans</option>
    <option value="gbp">Green Bay Packers</option>
    <option value="ss">Seattle Seahawks</option>
    <option value="cbr">Cleveland Browns</option>
    <option value="bb">Buffalo Bills</option>
    <option value="jj">Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
    <option value="ic">Indianapolis Colts</option>
    <option value="ht">Houston Texans</option>
    <option value="kcc">Kansas City Chiefs</option>
    <option value="md">Miami Dolphins</option>
    <option value="nep">New England Patriots</option>
    <option value="nyj">New York Jets</option>
    <option value="slr">Saint Louis Rams</option>
    <option value="nos">New Orleans Saints</option>
    <option value="mv">Minnesota Vikings</option>
    <option value="tbb">Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
    <option value="ac">Arizona Cardinals</option>
    <option value="af">Atlanta Falcons</option>
    <option value="sf49">San Francisco 49ers</option>
    <option value="sdc">San Diego Chargers</option>
    <option value="or">Oakland Raiders</option>
    <option value="db">Denver Broncos</option>
    <option value="cbe">Cincinnati Bengals</option>
    <option value="cp">Carolina Panthers</option>
    <option value="dl">Detroit Lions</option>
    <option value="cbea">Chicago Bears</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<br>
</body>
<html>
```

This is what I have so far, I'm having trouble hiding the second echo statement inside the if statement with isset() inside until a pick is made. The main point of this is to make it so I can take an html 'select' drop down list form with a submit "POST" feature able to be locked based on the days of the week, monday night it locks to Thursday morning it unlocks. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the php script that checks 'pick',  after the HTML code

```
<?php 

    //If statement to control pick selection "disabled/enabled"
if(strtotime("Today") == strtotime("Thursday") || strtotime("Friday") ||   strtotime("Saturday") || strtotime("Sunday") || strtotime("Monday")) {
echo '<h2>Make a selection! Picks are now  available</h2>';
}


?>

<html>
<body>

<h3>Pick</h3>

<div class="loginForm">
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Pick</legend>
    <select id="tm1" name="teams">
    <option value="null"> Please Select Your Pick</option>
    <option value="wr">Washington Redskins</option>
    <option value="nyg">New York Giants</option>
    <option value="pe">Philadelphia Eagles</option>
    <option value="dc">Dallas Cowboys</option>
    <option value="br">Baltimore Ravens</option>
    <option value="ps">Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
    <option value="tt">Tennessee Titans</option>
    <option value="gbp">Green Bay Packers</option>
    <option value="ss">Seattle Seahawks</option>
    <option value="cbr">Cleveland Browns</option>
    <option value="bb">Buffalo Bills</option>
    <option value="jj">Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
    <option value="ic">Indianapolis Colts</option>
    <option value="ht">Houston Texans</option>
    <option value="kcc">Kansas City Chiefs</option>
    <option value="md">Miami Dolphins</option>
    <option value="nep">New England Patriots</option>
    <option value="nyj">New York Jets</option>
    <option value="slr">Saint Louis Rams</option>
    <option value="nos">New Orleans Saints</option>
    <option value="mv">Minnesota Vikings</option>
    <option value="tbb">Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
    <option value="ac">Arizona Cardinals</option>
    <option value="af">Atlanta Falcons</option>
    <option value="sf49">San Francisco 49ers</option>
    <option value="sdc">San Diego Chargers</option>
    <option value="or">Oakland Raiders</option>
    <option value="db">Denver Broncos</option>
    <option value="cbe">Cincinnati Bengals</option>
    <option value="cp">Carolina Panthers</option>
    <option value="dl">Detroit Lions</option>
    <option value="cbea">Chicago Bears</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<br>
<?php


    if(isset($_POST['teams'])) {
        $pick = $_POST['teams'];
        echo '<br><p>You have made a selection,  feel free to change your pick until ONE HOUR before game time.<p><br>';
    }

?>
</body>
<html>
```